# How to use dynamic routes corectly?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Using Nuxt 3, I read the official documentation which is very poor: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/pages/#dynamic-routes

But I can't understand how to make it work correctly for dynamic routes.

I have my Product component:

```
pages
|___product
    |___[slug].vue
```

I want to link easily to the [slug] component, looking at the Vue Router doc, I did this:

```html
<NuxtLink :to="{path: `/product/${product.seo.slug}`, component: Product}" class="product-listing">
  .....
</NuxtLink>
```

It works, but it reload the whole page.
Did I miss something ?

Comment: What is `component: Product`, cannot see it anywhere in the API of vue router.? What happens if you hardcode the URL? Also, inspect the link via your devtools, it's strange that it does not work.

Comment: Saw it in the doc: https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html, but even with hardcoded URL, I won't have the transition, console is clean :(

Comment: What you've linking here is how to define a router manually, not what you pass to a `nuxt-link`. Do you have a [repro]?

Comment: Going to JS fiddle this, Nuxt3 says to rely on this plugin (Vue Router)

Comment: Prefer a codesandbox or stackblitz, JSfiddle is not the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
<NuxtLink :to="`/product/${product.seo.slug}`" class="product-listing">" 
    ...
</NuxtLink>
```